# Как сохранить csv в excel

Tags: excel, csv, xls

У меня возникла проблема при сохранении csv файла. Я хочу сохранить его в формате xls. У меня есть 4 столбца (date, name, address, about). Они все разделены запятными, но проблема в том, что в столбце about идёт текст, где может быть очень много запятых. Так вот, вопрос. Как сохранить csv в формат xls, чтобы у меня было всего 4 столбца.
P.S. в столбце date, name, address нет запятых.
Приведу пример из файла:

```
03.01.2023 (date),Мамонтёнок (Московский театр мюзикла) (name),Московский театр мюзикла (address),"Мюзикл для всей семьи - захватывающее театрально-музыкальное приключение в Африке.Что делает Мамонтёнок в Африке? Сможет ли он обрести друзей среди всезнающих попугаев, весёлых обезьянок и мудрых жирафов? И найдёт ли он себе уютный дом с заботливой мамой?Известный сюжет оброс новыми подробностями, симпатичными героями и диалогами. И всё это — под зажигательные песни Владимира Шаинского, Евгения Крылатова и Геннадия Гладкова на стихи Юрия Энтина и Григория Остера.Это спектакль о силе дружбы, важности надежды, упорстве на пути к заветной цели, бесконечном оптимизме, необъятной родительской любви и, конечно, об исполнении желаний (about).
```

Comment: *Значения, содержащие зарезервированные символы (двойная кавычка, запятая, точка с запятой, новая строка) обрамляются двойными кавычками ("). Если в значении встречаются кавычки — они представляются в файле в виде двух кавычек подряд.*

Answer (score 0):

А через какое ПО вы работаете с файлом: excel, программный скрипт, что-то ещё? Как будто самое простое решение открыть файл в Excel и пересохранить в формате ".xls". Проблемы с запятыми внутри полей обычно решаются использованием в качестве разделителя ";" вместо ",".

P. S. Попробовала создать ".csv" файл на основе приведенной строки, открыла в excel, пересохранила в формате ".xls", вроде проблем не возникло.

Comment: Работаю через microsoft excel, уже понял, как решить данную проблему, спасибо.
Для тех, кто наткнулся на этот вопрос - комментарий ниже

Answer (score 0):

Открываете microsoft excel (лично у меня стоит он), создаёте новую пустую книгу ( новый лист ). Далее:

1. Заходите во вкладку Данные - Получение внешних данных - из текста.
2. Выбираете свой csv файл.
3. Формат данных - с разделителями
4. Формат файла - Юникод
5. Выбираете ваш символ-разделитель
6. Формат данных столбца - выбираете сами в зависимости от того, в какой колонке какие данные
7. Нажимаете готово